# (Extended?) Travelling salesman Problem

Tags: algorithms, combinatorial-geometry

I've had a problem for several years, I can't get to solve : it seems similar to Travelling Salesman Person (I guess), except

- I need to visit a specific number of times
- the "distance criterion" is obviously a little different, or there's a trivial solution where you visit consecutively N times the same city. Actually, cities have a "weight" that may be positive or negative and the cumulative sum shall remain as neutral as possible (near zéro)

  I calculate this distance with([weigth(i-1)/2+weigth(i)/2])² (proposition)
- I don't particularly NEED to come back to starting point (but I think it could)

Let's say I need to visit 5*A(20), 4*B(-25), the trivial solution is ABABABABA, like :

```
____________________________________
|city | weight |cumulative|distance|
|_________________________|________|
|  A  |   20   |   20     |  100    =((0+20)/2)²
|  B  |  -25   |   -5     |   56.25 =((20-5)/2)²
|  A  |   20   |   15     |   25   |...
|  B  |  -25   |  -10     |    6.25|
|  A  |   20   |   10     |    0   |
|  B  |  -25   |  -15     |    6.25|
|  A  |   20   |    5     |   25   |
|  B  |  -25   |  -20     |   56.25|
|  A  |   20   |   20     |  100   |
|_________________________|________|
 total ->value to minimize|  375   |
                          |________|
```

But that is a trivial configuration, where the occurrences of >0 and <0 weights are "easy" to sequence.

Now, I try to find a nice sequence with let's say 6*A(26331), 6*B(38848), 3*C(-50976), 12*D(-10825) and 2*E(-43298), that's a little less obvious.

I had the idea to use genetic algorithm, but I don't handle the theory very well, and I only found examples with each city visited once.

Please if you have an idea, I'm listening. And if my question isn't clear enough, just tell me I'll try to improve.

Cheers !

Comment: The order of the 'cities' doesn't matter, right? And their cost is determined by the individual city alone (not their difference), right? So what does this have to do with the TSP? It is just a series sum that has to be optimized to minimum modulus...

Comment: Yes, the order matters, that's what I'm looking for actually. And the cost is determined by summing the weight of every city visited
It is linked to TSP because I'm looking for an algorithm, going from a bunch of cities to an ordered list. But maybe I'm wrong !

Comment: If you just sum up the cities' weights, then how can the order be relevant for the sum? Addition is commutative and associative...

Comment: Oh I see, then I must not be clear on my criterion. The idea is to keep the "cumulative" column as close to zero as possible. We can imagine a squared column representing the distance (that is not commutative and associative). I'll edit my question